# The <meter> tag is not displaying in ASP: repeater when loaded

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem when I tried to load the  tag inside the ASP Repeater but it's not showing inside the repeater. Here's my code and I attached a picture showing the meter tag. Your help is highly appreciated.
[image]

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Rink52" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <a href="#" class="hotspot" id="picpoint<%# (Eval("Points") - 1).ToString %>" style="background-color: <%# Eval("Color_Condition") %>;"><%# Eval("Points")  %>
                                            <span>
                                            Point Area <%# Eval("Points")  %> (in Inches)
                                            <br />
                                            Minimum Value: <%# Eval("Min_Value") %>
                                            <br />
                                            Maximum Value: <%# Eval("Max_Value")%>
                                            <br />
                                            Average: <%# Eval("DropDown_Value")%> 
                                            <meter min="0" max="1.8" value=" <%# Eval("DropDown_Value")%>  "></meter>
                                           </span></a>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, that should work.

However, "dropdown_value" does not look like a column name in the data source???

Say I have this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width: 20%; text-align: right">
            <h3>Hotel Name <%# Eval("HotelName") %>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Rating"
                    Style="margin-left: 20px"></asp:Label>
                <meter min="0" max="5"
                    value="<%#Eval("Rating") %>"></meter>
            </h3>
            <hr />
            <br />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code to load is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Repeater1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    Repeater1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

and result is this:

[image]

so, as a test, just put in a label , or something and "display"/"include" the value of  in your markup - what does it spit out???

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.

```
<meter value='<%# Eval("DropDown_Value") %>' min="0" max="2" ></meter>
```

Comment: Consider adding some details about your solution.